# TemplateDoesNotExist at django hosting 

Tags: python, django, django-templates

in the localhost , my code is running good on http://127.0.0.1:8000/twitter/  ,

but in the django hosting : http://zjm1126.alwaysdata.net/twitter/, it is show error :

```
TemplateDoesNotExist at /twitter/

home.html
```

home.html  is in

```
mysite:
   twitter
       templates 
            home.html
```

and i set this is settings.py

```
TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
)
```

and

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.comments',

    'twitter',
)
```

so what can i do ,

thanks

Comment: Can you post the line where you are rendering the template?

Comment: Also, check your TEMPLATES_DIR variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if there are missing templates included in your home.html.

If you have, say, `{% include "header.html" %}` in your home.html, and there's no header.html in the templates directory, Django still will throw `TemplateDoesNotExist home.html`, even though the actual missing template is not home.html, but the one included into it.

Comment: Recent discussion on the topic: http://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/django-developers/8cLjZkyKrOI/discussion

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this in settings.py

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'templates').replace('\\', '/'),
)
```

These lines says django to find templates in folders with names 'templates'.
Although in book author said this default behaviour without this code.